# is using 0 to search for 00:00:00 time is safe?

Tags: mysql

in my query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=428401650be79f63665b718f954a35bf
i wanna search for rows with time value of `00:00:00`

i noticed i can search for it with these `WHERE` conditions

```
WHERE `time` = 0
WHERE `time` = '0'
WHERE `time` = '0:00'
WHERE `time` = '00:00'
WHERE `time` = '00:00:00'
```

i wanna use `time = 0` as shortcut but do not know if it is safe to use

what is the safest option and best practice to follow?

Comment: _..do not know if it is safe to use..._ Define "safe" please.

Comment: @B001ᛦ that it is a common practice to use it and will not break in future updates and need to be updated to `00:00:00`

Comment: @B001ᛦ why is it allowed to search this row with value of 0 integer and is it interpreted as `00:00:00` in mysql background or query execution fixes it and it is a mistake?

Comment: @rhctomoefjklioizsx I'm not a mariadb expert, but in the documentation it says you can express times as numbers, for example `1:23:45` can be expressed as `12345`. So it probably works like that the other way around too. Just make sure that it doesn't match unwanted timestamps. Can you confirm if `WHERE time = 123` matches `00:01:23`, but not `01:01:23` for example?

Comment: @RoboRobok `WHERE time = 123` matches `00:01:23` but `01:01:23` does not even with `WHERE time = 1123` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=7a773fabbafb3800e203126b6e5e9133

Comment: @rhctomoefjklioizsx I think `01:01:23` would be `10123`. If it is, I'd say using `0` as `00:00:00` is 100% fine!

Comment: @RoboRobok this is only for mariadb and can not be used anywhere else?

Comment: @rhctomoefjklioizsx well, there's no time type in SQL standard at all, so it only comes as an extension to the standard. And what other systems use it, I don't know.